# Creating a looping square with java

Tags: java, loops

Full Disclosure:  Homework.

Explanation:  I cant understand my teacher.

Problem:

> Write a method called `printSquare` that takes in two integer
>   parameters, a `min` and a `max`, and  prints the numbers in the range from
>   `min` to `max` inclusive in a square pattern. The square  pattern is
>   easier to understand by example than by explanation, so take a look at
>   the sample  method calls and their resulting console output in the
>   table below.  Each line of the square consists of a circular sequence
>   of increasing integers between `min` and  `max`. Each line prints a
>   different permutation of this sequence. The first line begins with
>   min, the  second line begins with `min + 1`, and so on. When the
>   sequence in any line reaches `max`, it wraps  around back to `min`. You
>   may assume the caller of the method will pass a `min` and a `max`
>   parameter such that `min` is less than or equal to `max`

[image]

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make the numbers stop at the 'max' value and start over in the middle of the line.

This is what I have so far, apologies but I have trouble with for loops.

```
for(int i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    for(int d = 0; d < row; d++)
    {
        System.out.print(d+1);
    }
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

I know I used row twice, but its the only way i can get the compiler to form a square shape with the loop. Does anyone even remotely understand what i'm trying to do? :/

Comment: *I know I used row twice* then you understand that you should use another variable instead of `row` in one of those `for` loops, re read the homework exercise and think a bit more about it.

Comment: Think about the "virtual" starting index of each row. If the first row starts at 0 (i.e. `0 + 1`, `0 + 2` etc) what does the second row start at?

Comment: How would _you_ do it, if you had a pen and piece of paper? Once you figure that out, just tell the computer to do the same thing.

Comment: I would suggest not using the variable of the loop as value to print, you know those values won't change during the process, there's better options to use.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza   I've been looking at this for problem for a while now.  I need an explanation.  My teacher's second language is english and theres a breakdown somewhere in our attempt to understand each other.

Comment: your teacher is very clear in what he/she wants and the illustration is very much apt..:)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is actually a nice mathematical problem. Assume:

```
int side = to - from + 1; /// the size/width of the square.
```

the value at any point in the square (row, col) is:

```
from + ((row + col) % side)
```

you should be able to put that in your loops and "smoke it".

---

Edit based on comment asking for explanation.

The trick is to loop through all the positions in the 'matrix'. Given that the matrix is square, the loops are relatively simple, just two loops (nested) that traverse the system:

```
    final int side = to - from + 1;
    for (int row = 0; row < side; row++) {
        for(int col = 0; col < side; col++) {
            ... magic goes here....
        }
    }
```

Now, in this loop, we have the variables `row` and `col` which represent the cell in the matrix we are interested in. The value in that cell needs to be proportional to the distance it is from the origin..... let me explain.... If the origin is the top left (which it is), then the distances from the origin are:

```
0 1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
3 4 5 6 7
4 5 6 7 8
```

The distance is the sum of the row and the column...... (rows and columns start counting from 0).

The values we put in each matrix are limited to a fixed range. For the above example, with a square of size 5, it could have been specified as `printSquare(1,5)`.

The value in each cell is the from value (1 in this example) plus the distance from the origin... naively, this would look like:

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
3 4 5 6 7
4 5 6 7 8
5 6 7 8 9
```

here the values in the cell have exceeded the limit of 5, and we need to wrap them around... so, the trick is to 'wrap' the distances from the origin..... and the 'modulo' operator is great for that. First, consider the original 'origin distance' matrix:

```
0 1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 6
3 4 5 6 7
4 5 6 7 8
```

if we instead populate this matrix with 'the remainder of the distance when dividing by 5' (the modulo 5, or %5) we get the matrix:

```
0 1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 0
2 3 4 0 1
3 4 0 1 2
4 0 1 2 3
```

Now, if we add this 'modulo' result to the from value (1), we get our final matrix:

```
1 2 3 4 5
2 3 4 5 1
3 4 5 1 2
4 5 1 2 3
5 1 2 3 4
```

in a sense, all you need to know is that the value at each cell is:

```
the from value plus the remainder when you divide the 'distance' by the width.
```

Here's the code I tested with:

```
public static final String buildSquare(final int from, final int to) {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(side * side);

    final int side = to - from + 1;

    for (int row = 0; row < side; row++) {
        for(int col = 0; col < side; col++) {
            sb.append( from + ((row + col) % side) );
        }
        sb.append("\n");
    }
    return sb.toString();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(buildSquare(1, 5));
    System.out.println(buildSquare(3, 9));
    System.out.println(buildSquare(5, 5));
    System.out.println(buildSquare(0, 9));
    System.out.println(buildSquare(0, 3));
}
```

Comment: Using the [remainder (modulus) operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) to count periodically is a very clever solution! Nice!

Comment: I don't suppose you'd take your time and explain this a little more in detail for me?   I ended up failing the question because I didn't turn it in on time.   I wanted to understand more than get it right so I wasn't paying attention to the assignment clock. :3

Comment: No problem, done. And good luck in your studies. This, for the record, is a 'nice' problem it has a nice mathematical component, and an 'elegant' solution in a program. It's a good assignment. I must remember this.

Answer (score 3):

Since this is homework, I'll just give a hint.

> I cannot for the life of me figure out how to make the numbers stop at the 'max' value and start over in the middle of the line.

Here's one way to do it.

- Create the first number twice in an array.  Taking the `printSquare(1, 5)` example, create an int array of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.
- Use a loop to loop through the array, starting with element zero and ending with element 4, and another loop to display 5 digits (max - min + 1).

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
    int i,j,k;
    for(i=min;i<=max;i++) {
        for(j=i;j<=max;j++) {
            System.out.print(j);
        }
        for(k=min;k<i;k++){
            System.out.print(k);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

1. loop from min value to max value and put all the numbers in an array
2. now loop again from min value to max value

   each time print the array and do a circular shift (for circular shift you can find lot of example in SO)

Answer (score 0):

I think @rolfl's solution is the cleanest. I'd recommend going with that.

You can find another simple solution by observing that each output in your "square" simply shifts the first element to the end the list of numbers. To imitate this, you can put all the numbers from `min` to `max` in a data structure like [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) or [`ArrayDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) where you can easily add/remove items from both ends, then you'd print the contents in order, and *shift* the first entry to the end. E.g., `coll.addLast(coll.removeFirst())`. If you repeat that process `max - min + 1` times, you should get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

no array no problem you can easily solve.
it work with any range of number.

```
 static void printSquare(int min, int max){
        int len = max - min + 1;
        int copy_min = min,  permanent_min = min;
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j< len; j++){
                if(min > max)
                    if(min % len < permanent_min)
                        System.out.print((min % len )+ len);
                    else
                        System.out.print(min % len);
                else
                    System.out.print(min);
                min++;
            }
            min = ++copy_min;
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            public static void printSquare(int min, int max)  {
                
                for (int i = min; i <= (max -min)+min; i++)  {
                    
                    for( int j =i; j <= max ; j++) {                
                        System.out.print(j);   
                        } 
                    for (int j1= min; j1<= i * 1 - 1; j1++) {
                        System.out.print(j1);
                        }
                    System.out.println();
                }
                
            }
```